# Django: How to properly handle two websites at the same time with a shared database?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, virtualhost

I've researched on how to handle multiple websites with Django but nothing seemed really convincing to me: [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/2zybq5/connect_two_django_instances_to_same_database/), [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-users/uA_XyGYKn2o/km80RXBB2uMJ) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168081/how-do-you-setup-a-django-project-with-different-sites-using-the-same-data)

Here is what I have now:

A single Django project running on a server, with two apps. One for the API (with django REST Framework) and an other app which basically consumes the API and display the datas (retrieved directly in the database). My database is Oracle and on a separate server for robustness reasons.

Here is what I would like to have:

Two websites, one would be the API (certain users use only the API) and the other one would be the website (for the other users).
I obviously need those two websites to share the same database (but this shouldn't be to hard to handle in the settings.py file), and I also need to use the same Models, Admin, etc...

How can I handle that with being as DRY as possible ? If I make two django project, I'll have to duplicate my models, my admin, and certain business classes and functions... Which could be a pain to maintain.

The alternative would be to play around with virtualhosts and url redirections to make it seamless.

What do you think is the best solution ? And can you provide an example of implementation ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**There are few options:**

1. Create 2 projects and a django application. You create the django application for the common code, like the models. Then you create 2 projects and use that application in both of them.
2. Create 1 project with 3 applications 1 application for common code, 1 for API and 1 for app. The API and app application will use the common code application.
3. Create just 1 project with 1 application. You'll have to create different views for the API and for the app and map a different url for each one.

The options are sorted by overhead while the first option has the most overhead, but it's the most organized solution.

Which is best? it depends on the size of your project. The bigger - the more the overhead will pay off. If you don't know what is going to be the size of the project in the future, then I would start with the third option, and as the project grows, move towards the second and first options.